# many-to-many product-category relation with subcategories

Tags: mysql

hello guys i have something like this:

categories

```
+--------+---------------+--------------+
| ctg_id | ctg_parent_id | ctg_discount |
+--------+---------------+--------------+
|      1 |              0|           10 |
|      2 |              1|              |
|      3 |              2|              |
+--------+---------------+--------------+

products      products_ctgs_relation
+------+      +------+-------------+
| p_id |      | p_id | category_id |
+------+      +------+-------------+
|     1|      |   3  |            3|
|     2|      |      |             |
|     3|      |      |             |
+------+      +------+-------------+
```

the product with id=3 should get 10% discount, because he belongs to a category where some of the parents of this category have discount. 
Is it possible to get the product and the discount in 1 query - starting from products table ? i.e select p.* from products..

Comment: take a look at [the JOIN syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: MySQL doesn't support recursive functions, so it is not well-suited to this "adjacency list" model for storing hierarchical data.  You would do well to investigate alternative models, such as "nested sets" and "transitive closures".

Comment: @Todor . . . How deep do the parents nest?

Comment: For now is 3 levels but who knows for the future..

Comment: Also see Mike Hillyer's ancient but excellent article on the subject. http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way of doing it. mysql does not support hierarchical queries like Oracle or SQL Server do.

But i googled around and found this article, it might help you:

http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/